# Cannot display data in Jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a little problem, I'm just trying to display the data in my table, it was working 3 days ago but I don't know what I did .I'm putting the code snippets here. Thank you in advance for your help.

My Servlet

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
         
listBook(request, response);
}private void listBook(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException  {
    List<Book> books = book.getAllBooks();
    request.setAttribute("books", books);
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE_LISTBOOK).forward(request, response);

}
```

BookImpl :

```
@Override
public List<Book> getAllbooks() {
    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
    try {
        c = MysqlDaoFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
        ps = c.prepareStatement(SQL_SELECT);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
         
        while (rs.next()) {
            Book book = new Book();
            book.setIdBook(rs.getInt("id"));
            book.setTitle(rs.getString("title"));
            book.setIsbn(rs.getString("isbn"));
            book.setEdition(rs.getString("edition"));
            book.setPublicationDate(rs.getDate("publicationDate"));
            book.setResume(rs.getString("resume"));
            book.setNbPage(rs.getInt("nbPage"));
            book.setBarcode(rs.getString("barcode"));
            book.setImage(rs.getString("image"));      
            book.setCategory(category.findById(rs.getInt("id")));

            books.add(book);
            }
    }
```

CategoryImpl :

```
private Category findById(String sql, int id) {
    Connection connection = null;
    Category category=null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        connection = MysqlDaoFactory.getInstance().getConnection();
        ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * from category where id=?");
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            category = new Category();
            int id2 = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("id"));
            String category1 = rs.getString("category");
            category.setId(id2);
            category.setCategory(category1);
             
           }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        MysqlConnectionFactory.closeConnection(connection);
        MysqlConnectionFactory.closeResultSet(rs);
    }
    return category;
}
```

}

JSP :

```
<c:forEach items="${books}" var="books">
                   <tr>
                       <th><c:out value="${books.idBook}"/></th>
                       <th><c:out value="${books.title}"/></th>
                       <th><c:out value="${books.isbn}"/></th>
                       <th><c:out value="${books.edition}"/></th>
                       <th><c:out value="${books.publicationDate}"/></th>
                       <th><c:out value="${books.resume}"/></th>
                       <th><c:out value="${books.barcode}"/></th>
                       <th><c:out value="${books.image}"/></th>
                       <th><c:out value="${books.category.category}"/></th>
                       
                                               
                   </tr>
               </c:forEach>
```

Output :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<!-- meta -->

<meta charset="utf-8">
```

```
                    <tr>

                        <th>test</th>

                        <th>test</th>

                        <th>test</th>

                        <th>test</th>

       <th>1111-05-05</th>

           <th>test</th>

       <th>test</th>

                        <th>test</th>

                        <th></th> ---> Empty
```

I think the problem comes from the method "FindById"
SORRY if it's not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem has been solved, I took the wrong ID can we close this subject ?